# How to apply css in iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

Here is my Iframe editor, I want to change some css inside editor , when I want to try to apply css, iframe css doesn't get.

```
     <div id="editor" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
        <iframe src="https://editor.unlayer.com/1.0.55/editor.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="min-width: 1024px; min-height: 100%; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0px;">
        </iframe>
        </div>
```

so , How can I apply css by using DOM?

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-ride-nbrj6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: yes , but how can i apply css by iframe without using ID or classname ? In my iframe , There is no id,classname. The problem is that I can not apply css .

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the style sheet inside the iframe, or on the source page would be better.

Comment: how can i do that